# Create a global computed property in a plugin in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, computed-properties

I'm trying to create a global computed property from within a Vue 3 plugin, so that my property can be used reactively in any component. I am using the [standard](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) Vue 3 pattern:

```js
app.config.globalProperties.$foo = ...
```

This works great to let me access `this.$foo` from any component. However, I also want to trigger behavior when `this.$foo` is **set**. But when I try to make it a settable computed property, like this—

```js
app.config.globalProperties.$foo = computed({
  get: () => ...
  set: () => ...
})
```

—it doesn't behave like a computed property: If I run `this.$foo = 'bar'` from a component, it simply overwrites the property, without triggering the computed setter. (Testing it on a computed without a setter, the property is also simply overwritten, where Vue would normally throw a warning.)

How can I make a global computed with a setter? Is there something I am missing here about how global properties (or computed properties in the Vue 3 composition API) are supposed to work?

Comment: I think, globalProperties are static properties, non-reactive.

Comment: You made $foo a computed, so you can modify it through `$foo.value`. `this` isn't used, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: How about simply exporting your computed in one file and importing it wherever you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computed()` returns a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref), so its value must be accessed through the `.value` property. Setting `$foo` directly would just overwrite the reference to some new value instead of modifying the `computed` ref's value:

```js
this.$foo = 'bar'        // ❌ overwrites the computed ref
this.$foo.value = 'bar'  // ✅ sets computed ref's value; triggers setter
```

You likely need reactivity, and a `computed` ref with a getter/setter would need to use another `ref` for that:

```js
// main.js
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
⋮
let foo = ref(123)
app.config.globalProperties.$foo = computed({
  get: () => foo.value,
  set: value => foo.value = value,
})
```

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    logFoo() {
      console.log(this.$foo.value) // => 123
    },
    updateFoo() {
      this.$foo.value++
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-global-computed-ref?file=src/main.js)